# Order of generic parameters in typescript causes the parameter to be interfered as {}

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write typings for compose function for the following scenario.

```
  interface ReducerBuilder<InS, OutS> {

    }
    interface State {
      hue2: number,
      hue3: string,
      hue: string;
    }

    declare function createBaseReducer <K>(initialState: K): ReducerBuilder<K, K> ;
    declare function createReducerTestI <K>(builder: ReducerBuilder<K, K>): ReducerBuilder<K, K>;

    declare function compose<TArg,TResult, TResult1>(f2: (arg: TResult1) => TResult, f1: (arg: TArg) => TResult1): (arg: TArg) => TResult;
    declare function composeRev<TResult, TArg, TResult1>(f1: (arg: TArg) => TResult1, f2: (arg: TResult1) => TResult): (arg: TArg) => TResult;

    const state : State = { hue2: 5, hue3: "aa", hue: "aa" };
    const built = createReducerTestI(createBaseReducer(state));

    const x0 = compose(createReducerTestI, createBaseReducer)(state);
    const x1 = compose(createReducerTestI, (arg: State) => createBaseReducer(arg))(state); 
    const x2 = composeRev((arg: State) => createBaseReducer(arg), createReducerTestI)(state);
```

- Type for `x0` is `ReducerBuilder<{},{}>`.  I understand that at args
  cannot be interfered here because the function returned from compose
  has no information about the type of arguments.
- Type for  `x1` is `ReducerBuilder<{},{}>`. I don't get why the type here
  is `{}`. I explicitly say `TArg` is a type of `State`. I suspect that
  Typescript is trying to interfere `TResult1` from left to right and it
  can't get it from `f2` argument.
- Type for `x2` is `ReducerBuilder<State,State>` - success. All I did was
  just to revert the order of parameters so `TResult1` could be
  interfered from left to right.

I don't really want to revert the order of arguments. Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to say thank you for this question, I got caught up in the "what is going on here" and realized that I was having a lot of fun. I'll just list out what I have discovered so far.

First off, you need to add something to `ReducerBuilder<InS, OutS>` the type is being inferred to be `{}` which is causing other issues since TArg is also being inferred to be`{}`. As far as I can tell, the root of the problem is not the order of the parameters. It's a failure of inferred types. I'm not actually sure how it should infer them so I won't go into my speculation of what is going on, but enumerating through the various ways of calling is a little more enlightening:

```
const x0 = compose(createReducerTestI, createBaseReducer)(state);
const x1 = compose(createReducerTestI, (arg: State) => createBaseReducer(arg))(state);
const x2 = compose((arg: ReducerBuilder<State, State>) => createReducerTestI(arg), createBaseReducer)(state);
const x3 = compose((arg: ReducerBuilder<State, State>) => createReducerTestI(arg), (arg: State) => createBaseReducer(arg))(state);

const x4 = composeRev(createBaseReducer, createReducerTestI)(state);
const x5 = composeRev(createBaseReducer, (arg: ReducerBuilder<State, State>) => createReducerTestI(arg))(state);
const x6 = composeRev((arg: State) => createBaseReducer(arg), createReducerTestI)(state);
const x7 = composeRev((arg: State) => createBaseReducer(arg), (arg: ReducerBuilder<State, State>) => createReducerTestI(arg))(state);
```

Only `x3`,`x6`, and `x7` show the correct return type. `x3`, and `x7` show the correct return type because the arguments don't need to be inferred, but I have no idea why `x6` works at all. Based on `x6` working I would assume that either `x2`, or everything except `x0` and `x4` would work.

Instead, besides the ones that return correctly, what I see is everything returns `TResult`, except `x4` *actually* returning `ReducerBuilder<{}, {}>`? This is odd behavior since it's just the order of the parameters that is causing it.

The new TypeScript 2.8 gives you `ReturnType<T>`, which would save you from having to specify the type between the two functions. But I don't know if that would actually "fix" the infer problem.

If you just need a type definition, you can do it by just specifying the return types.

Example 1:

```
const composedA = compose<State, ReducerBuilder<State, State>, ReducerBuilder<State, State>>(createReducerTestI, createBaseReducer);
const x0 = composedA(state);
```

or, as you already pointed out with your `built` variable:

Example 2:

```
const composedB = (arg: State) => createReducer(createBaseReducer(arg));
const x0 = composedB(state);
```

But that's not exactly helpful in a description file. I feel like the way of composing the functions is doing what is in example 2. However, it would probably be more accurate to create overloaded versions of compose, so that you can control through the types what is, and isn't possible to compose. In the following code I created 1 version of your compose, and another of a ridiculous one to show how you would do this. It also means that you can reduce the types that you need in order to be explicit about the functions it's possible to compose.

Function Overloading:

```
interface State1 {
    hue2: number;
    hue3: string;
    hue: string;
}

interface State2 {
    hue4: number;
    hue3: string;
    hue: string;
}

interface ReducerBuilder<InS, OutS> { in: InS; out: OutS; }
interface RediculousObject<InS, OutS> { a: InS; b: OutS; }

type TA_1<T> = ReducerBuilder<T, T>;
type CTA_1<T> = (a: T) => TA_1<T>;
type CTB_1<T> = (a: TA_1<T>) => TA_1<T>;

type TA_2<T, Y> = RediculousObject<T, Y>;
type CTA_2<T, Y> = (a: T) => TA_2<T, Y>;
type CTB_2<T, Y> = (b: Y) => CTA_2<T, Y>;
type CTC_2<T, Y> = (a: T, b: Y) => TA_2<T, Y>;

declare function _compose <T>(a: CTB_1<T>, b: CTA_1<T> | CTB_1<T>): CTA_1<T>;
declare function _compose <T, Y>(a: CTB_2<T, Y>, b: CTA_2<T, Y> | CTB_2<T, Y>): CTC_2<T, Y>;

const state1: State1 = { hue2: 5, hue3: "aa", hue: "aa" };
const state2: State2 = { hue4: 5, hue3: "aa", hue: "aa" };

declare function createBaseReducer <K>(initialState: K): ReducerBuilder<K, K>;
declare function createReducerTestI <K>(builder: ReducerBuilder<K, K>): ReducerBuilder<K, K>;
const f0 = _compose<State1>(createReducerTestI, createBaseReducer)(state1);

declare function _rediculous(a: State2): (b: State1) => RediculousObject<State1, State2>;
const f1 = _compose<State1, State2>(_rediculous, _rediculous)(state1, state2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here involves an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9366) in TypeScript where the compiler doesn't really know how to do generic type inference over higher-order functions where the functions are themselves generic.  According to [a comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15680#issuecomment-307571917) by [Anders Hejlsberg](https://github.com/ahejlsberg),

> This is a consequence of inference working left-to-right for contextually typed arguments. To solve it in the general case would require some form of unification, but that might in turn uncover other issues...

which is in line with your discovery that the order of parameters matters.

It looks like contextual inference of higher order generic functions may be quite difficult (according to comments on that GitHub issue and [linked issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9949#issuecomment-267490091)) to implement properly.

In the absence of such an implementation, you probably need to pick a workaround.  These include @Camron's [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48917684/2887218) to specify type parameters explicitly when calling `compose()`, <strike>or wait for TypeScript 2.8 and use [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) to reduce the number of type parameters you need</strike>.  The simplest workaround is to leave the parameters in the "reverse" order.

Hope that was at least of some use.  Good luck!

Edit: I tried using conditional types with something like `ReturnType<>` and `ArgumentType<>`, but it still doesn't work.  The problem where the generic type parameters of the higher-order function become `{}` remains.